# Why this functions are illegal?

Tags: c, pointers

Consider we have this declaration.
`char *str = “xyz”;`

Why `puts(*str)`; and `putchar(str);` are considered as illegal functions in C?

Comment: `puts` requires a `const char *`, but `*str` has type `char`.  And `putchar` requires an `int`, while `str` has type `char *`.  If the types aren't compatible, it's an error.  You should try to find a tutorial that covers basic types in C.

Comment: Those examples are _not_ considered "illegal functions".  They are invalid function calls due to type mismatch.  `puts` expects a `char*` type, but you have provided `char` which if allowed would attempt to convert a character value into a memory location and then read a null-terminated string from that location.  `putchar` expects a character value but you've provided a pointer.  Both these things are invariably caused by programmer error, which is why the compiler treats them as errors.

Answer (score 0):

To put simply -  a char* is equivalent to arrays in other languages (kinda)

When you write *str - you are deferencing the pointer to the array which essentially means it gives you the frist character in the string  - and puts takes a string not a character

Inversely putchar takes a char but str is a char pointer.

If you wanted to use them correctly you would use `puts(str)` to print the string and `putchar(*str)` to put the first character of the string

Consider researching pointers in C (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm) and welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

First, in terms of terminology they're not considered "illegal functions", they're considered "invalid function arguments" as in you have a type mismatch. In other words, both those functions are "legal", however you're just calling them incorrectly.

In C when you say `char*` you mean "pointer to one or more elements of type `char`. This is, in C terms, very similar to an array.

When you say `char* x = "y"` and then `*x` that's *de-referencing the pointer*, or in other words, the same thing as `x[0]`, which is of type `char`, just a single "character".

So when viewed in context:

- The `putchar()` function wants a `char` argument, `char*` is unacceptable.
- The `puts()` function wants a `char*` argument, `char` is unacceptable.

Since C is a strongly typed language you rarely get to pass in something that's "close enough", as there are few cases where that exists. The notable examples of that are implicit conversions between different floating point types, or floating point to int, as well as within different integer types. Other than that you don't have much latitude.